# Batch file help, output results of a for / do string

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch statement here, although for some reason it does not output the output to a file.

```
for /f %%a in (items.lst) do shop -r items.text %%a > result.lst
```

It works with normal statements, although with the FOR and DO statements its not working, could anyone shed any light on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop deletes the results on every iteration. Did you mean to use `>>`?

Comment: ty, I found another way around the situation

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in parenthesis.

```
( for /f %%a in (items.lst) do shop -r items.text %%a) > result.lst
```

Then you redirect the complete output to `result.lst`, else you redirect for each iteration to `result.lst` with new creation of the file